# Accessing files in hadoop distributed cache

Tags: hadoop

I want to use the distributed cache to allow my mappers to access data. In main, I'm using the command

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/peter/cacheFile/testCache1"), conf);
```

Where /user/peter/cacheFile/testCache1 is a file that exists in hdfs

Then, my setup function looks like this:

```
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    Path[] localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
    //etc
}
```

However, this localFiles array is always null.

I was initially running on a single-host cluster for testing, but I read that this will prevent the distributed cache from working. I tried with a pseudo-distributed, but that didn't work either

I'm using hadoop 1.0.3

thanks
Peter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Files not put correctly into distributed cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708947/files-not-put-correctly-into-distributed-cache)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Problem here was that I was doing the following:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/peter/cacheFile/testCache1"), conf);
```

Since the Job constructor makes an internal copy of the conf instance, adding the cache file afterwards doesn't affect things. Instead, I should do this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/peter/cacheFile/testCache1"), conf);
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
```

And now it works. Thanks to Harsh on hadoop user list for the help.

Comment: Harsh is indeed a godsend! .. Wasted quite a number of hours with the same. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();  
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/userpetercacheFiletestCache1"),job.getConfiguration());
```

You can also do it in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Once the Job is assigned to with a configuration object, 
ie `Configuration conf = new Configuration();`

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
```

And then if deal with attributes of conf  as shown below, eg

```
conf.set("demiliter","|");
```

or

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/peter/cacheFile/testCache1"), conf);
```

Such changes would not be reflected in a pseudo cluster or cluster how ever it would work with local environment.

Answer (score 2):

This version of code ( which is slightly different from the above mentioned constructs) has always worked for me.

```
//in main(String [] args)
Job job = new Job(conf,"Word Count"); 
...
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(/user/peter/cacheFile/testCache1), job.getConfiguration());
```

I didnt see the complete setup() function in Mapper code

```
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

    Path[] dataFile = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);

    // [0] because we added just one file.
    BufferedReader cacheReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(dataFile[0])));
    // now one can use BufferedReader's readLine() to read data

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Somum, it worked for me. I checked with hadoop 1.2.1