# mapreduce how to share global const variable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I allow all of my mappers to have access to one variable, for example a `TreeMap` object, without having each mapper to re-construct the `TreeMap` every time? The object will never be modified again once it's constructed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider putting the contents of the `TreeMap` object in the [`Distributed Cache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746561/accessing-files-in-hadoop-distributed-cache). If it is a small amount of data you can place the object contents in your configuration object:

```
conf.set("key", "value");
```

then use the JobConf object to access it in your mapper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have a question though, regarding the distributed cache, how much would the overhead be for each mapper to request the resource? Theoretically I want each physical node to have one copy of the resource so all mappers have access to it, or is that not possible since MapReduce can span thousands of nodes?

Comment: The resource I am sharing is the index of all possible words in an array to calculate vector similarity, thus it can be upwards to a few tens of thousands of entries.

Comment: @Jin the distributed cache is copied to each task before started, so accessing the distributed cache is a local file access.

Comment: Sorry for coming late to the party but @ThomasJungblut thanks for answering like a boss.